# Error 404 on GWT Development

Tags: gwt

Why does every time i try to run my code on eclipse it will display this on my console, well in fact ElementalArDemo.html is already on the war folder? and also what does error 404 means on GWT Development mode?

**Aug 11, 2014 5:16:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /ElementalArDemo.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 means that the file is is not found. The Logging message No file found for: /ElementalArDemo.html is telling you that the file is missing or misspelled. Make sure that the server you are using has the correct file path to your war or your exploded war directory.